# Creating docker image with Kotlin multimodule spring project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, jib

Hello @stackoverflow community,

I have a Kotlin Spring Boot application with following structure

```
.
├── build.gradle.kts
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── pipeline.yml
├── services
│   └── environment
│       ├── build.gradle.kts
│       └── src
│           └── main
│               └── kotlin
│                   └── com
│                       └── demo
│                           └── app
│                               └── services
│                                   └── environment
│                                       ├── controller
│                                       │   └── EnvironmentController.kt
│                                       ├── model
│                                       │   └── Environment.kt
│                                       └── repository
│                                           └── EnvironmentRepository.kt
├── settings.gradle.kts
└── web
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    └── src
        └── main
            ├── kotlin
            │   └── com
            │       └── demo
            │           └── app
            │               └── DemoApplication.kt
            └── resources
                └── application.properties
```

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.3.RELEASE" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.0" apply false
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.0" apply false
}

allprojects {
    group = "com.demo"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
        targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    }

    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "14"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply {
        plugin("io.spring.dependency-management")
    }
}
```

services/environment/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot")

    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring")
    application
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.demo.app.services.environment"
}
```

web/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version "2.5.0"

    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring")
    application
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":services:environment"))

    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.demo.app"
}


jib {
    from {
        image = "openjdk:14-jdk-slim"
    }
    to {
        image = "demo/app"
    }
}
```

Somehow when I build my docker image with jibDockerBuild the submodule "services.environment" is missing in the running application inside the docker container and I cant access the REST API I wrote in this submodule.

... I am really stuck at this problem and cant get any further and I am hoping for help.

Thanks,
Andrioshe

Comment: Is `:service:environment` a pure compile-time Java library or a standalone service running and listening on its own port apart from `:web`? If a library, are you saying `:web` throws `ClassNotFoundException` when you're trying to use classes from `:service:environment`? Have you checked if `/app/libs/` in the Docker image contains the JAR file for `:service:environment`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add following lines to the build.grade.kts in :services:environment

```
tasks {
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

and set the main-class in :web to "de.demo.app.DemoApplication***Kt***"

Comment: If that was the case, the issue is unrelated to Jib. If you don't enable the `jar` task, even `./gradlew clean assemble` (i.e., building from a clean state) would fail if `:web` were referencing classes from `:services:environment`.

Comment: Yes, also ./gradlew build had problems. I am glad I could fix it, you gave me indirectly the tip to look for the jar file otherwhise I would still search the mistake